# toquelib behaves different with static and dynamic linking

Tags: gcc, cluster-computing, dynamic-linking, hpc, torque

This is puzzling me...
I have a code that looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pbs_ifl.h>

int doSomeStuff()
{
    char *server_name;
    int c;

    server_name = pbs_default();

    c = pbs_connect(server_name);
    printf("pbs_errno %d\n",pbs_errno);

    // do some stuff

    pbs_disconnect(c);
}
```

When I compile it with:

```
gcc -static -o executablename sourcefile.c -ltorque
```

It works allright, compiling with '-static'. pbs_errno is 0 and I can do my stuff.

But if I remove the '-static' flag it starts giving me this message when I run it:

```
munge: Error: Unable to access "/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2": No such file or directory
```

So... I start the munge service (munged) and it stops complaining about it, but instead I get pbs_errno=15033 and can't get anything from the cluster (do my stuff).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I delete de question or answer it, but it seems so be solved... so I'm posting the solution here.

I had 2 versions of the lib installed, one via yum other via source.
Since only the compiled code had the static libs, when I was linking -static gcc was linking with the compiled code and when I was linking dynamic it was linking with the yum version.

I just had to enforce the linking with the right libs adding the following flag when liking:

```
-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
```